# What will happen when two threads execute cache.putIfAbsent at the same time?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, concurrenthashmap, futuretask

I am learning `Java Concurrency in Practice`, but some code confused me:

```
private final ConcurrentHashMap<A, Future<V>> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<A, Future<V>>();

private final Computable<A, V> c;

public Memoizer(Computable<A, V> c) {
    this.c = c;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.demo.buildingblocks.Computable#compute(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
public V compute(final A arg) throws InterruptedException {

    while (true) {
        Future<V> f = cache.get(arg);
        if (f == null) {
            // 
            Callable<V> eval = new Callable<V>() {
                @Override
                public V call() throws Exception {
                    return c.compute(arg);
                }
            };
            FutureTask<V> ft = new FutureTask<V>(eval);
            // what will happen when two threads arrive here at the same time?
            f = cache.putIfAbsent(arg, ft);
            if (f == null) {
                f = ft;
                ft.run();
            }
        }
        try {
            return f.get();
        } catch (CancellationException e) {
            cache.remove(arg, f);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            launderThrowable(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I just can't understand, since `putIfAbsent` can only guarantee `put` operation is atomatic，and they all return null, if the two threads can both enter the `run` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`putIfAbsent` guarantees thread safety not only in the sense that it won't corrupt your data, but also in the sense that it **always** works on an up-to-date copy of the data.

Also, not it returns the previous value from the map, if such a value existed. So the first call to `putIfAbsent` would succeed, and return `null`, since there is no previous value. The second call will block until the first one succeeds, and then return the first value that was put in the map, causing the second `run()` to never be called.

Comment: I mean, the two call arrive at the same time, and both of the called `putIfAbsend` method, and then return null, if this sense can occur?

Comment: No, this cannot occur. **One** of the calls will always occur first, and the second will wait for it to complete. This is part of a `ConcurrentMap`'s tread safety.

Comment: I read the source code of `ConcurrentMap`, and found `lock` in the `put` operation, so what you said is right, this will not occur, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The source of all atomic implementations is the `compareAndSet(expected, newValue)` method. So if 2 threads arrive and each one likes to set an element that is at - let's say - 1 to 3, the following happens:

```
Thread A: value.compareAndSet(1, 3) - success: value is now 3, return true.
Thread B: value.compareAndSet(1, 3) - error: value is not 1 as expected, return false.
```

Which of those threads arrive first is undefined, but since the compareAndSet is an atomic function, it is guaranteed that threads won't interfere each other while executing.